# Is there a slow speed walnut grinder?

Tags: equipment, nuts, grinding

I am currently grinding walnuts at home using a manual grinder and I would like to use an electric one.

I have seen there are several models available on the market, but I haven't seen one which can be adjusted for slow (speed) grinding. This is useful when the walnuts aren't perfectly dried.

So, I am looking for a home-use walnut grinder with a low speed setting (similar to the speed achieved using a manual grinder). Does anybody know if such a grinder exists?

Comment: For more context, what sort of results are you looking for from your low-speed grinding? I use my **food processor** to grind nuts, and with the *PULSE* button I can get pretty much any texture I want, from a coarse chop all the way down to smooth nut butter. Also, by taking short breaks between pulses, it avoid heating the nuts undesirably.